# How to save and restore bitmap before close app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanna make replaceable personal background for app's users. When they change picture I can't save it before close app. I try shared preferences but not working for bitmap. How can I save and restore bitmap before close app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//use this method to save your bitmap, call this method when you have bitmap
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap pBitmap){
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("folderName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(directory, "fileName.png");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        //save this path in shared preference to use in future.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SAVE_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

use this method to get bitmap from file path that you saved

```
private void getBitmapFromPath(String pFilePath) {
    try {
        File f = new File(pFilePath);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        //use this bitmap as you want
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for saving and retrieving file path

```
    //This for saving file path 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("FILE_PATH_KEY", filePath).apply();

    //this for getting saved file path
    String filePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("FILE_PATH_KEY", "path not retrieved successfully!");
```

Comment: I Save file path with this code,
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("image_key", filePath); -- I Save File Path
        editor.commit();
        super.onPause();

After I try get code from save prefences with this code
sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            pFilePath = sharedpreferences.getString("resim_anahtari",""); but its not working

Comment: your key is different to save and get value from sharedPreference, correct it

Comment: I have added answer to save and retrieve path

Comment: Thats work! Thank you for helping me. And sorry my bad, I miss that part.